# Identify an element with in an angular website using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying automate an Angular application. The only drawback I have at the moment is that I don't want to use Protractor, I want to automate using Selenium/Eclipse. I have tried it but the problem is that locator keeps changing whenever I rerun the test. I have browsed through the net and found no concrete solution to this. Snippet of one field in the websites:

```html
<input _ngcontent-wle-c93="" formcontrolname="FirstName" mattooltip="Enter First Name" maxlength="50" matinput="" placeholder="First Name" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c47-3 ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" cdk-describedby-host="" id="mat-input-0" aria-invalid="true" aria-required="false" aria-describedby="mat-error-0">
```

`id="mat-input-0"` keeps changing

Comment: Then use one of the attributes that doesn't change, or add your own more stable locators (e.g. `data-test-id="some-useful-input"`). Even if you *are* using Protractor that's better than coupling your E2E tests to Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your element, you have a couple of options to access it

```
<input _ngcontent-wle-c93="" formcontrolname="FirstName" mattooltip="Enter First Name" maxlength="50" matinput="" placeholder="First Name" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c47-3 ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" cdk-describedby-host="" id="mat-input-0" aria-invalid="true" aria-required="false" aria-describedby="mat-error-0">
```

Let's take it one by one

CSS_SELECTOR

```
drive.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[formcontrolname='FirstName'][placeholder='First Name']"));
```

XPATH

```
drive.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@placeholder,'First Name')]"));
```

or

```
drive.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@formcontrolname,'FirstName')]"));
```

or both

```
drive.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@formcontrolname,'FirstName') and (@placeholder, 'FirstName')]"));
```

same for CSS_SELECTOR - I've shown to you the code with both, but you can access it even by specifying one attribute for your input element

Comment: Loads of Thanks. Your answer was the perfect solution. This is what I was looking for. Although CSS worked perfectly and I assume xpath would have worked as well but when  I rechecked the code, it had "matinput placeholder" not just "placeholder".  I tried with the matinputplaceholder but did not work. If you could just tell me why it did not work, that would be great. Again, Thanks a bunch.

Comment: matinput is an empty attribute, you cannot use it as [matinputplaceholder] cause placeholder is an attribute that has value, if you set matinput value in code, your browser will generate it differently and then you can use it //input[contains(@matinput, 'value') and (@placeholder,'value')]

Answer (score 0):

To identify the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using [java](/questions/tagged/java) and `XPATH`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class, 'mat-input-element') and @formcontrolname='FirstName'][@placeholder='First Name']"))).click();
  ```
- Using [python](/questions/tagged/python) and `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.mat-input-element[formcontrolname='FirstName'][placeholder='First Name']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : For *python* clients you have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```